# Facing issues in bulk update via data loader

Tags: data-loader, campaign-member

I am trying to update the records in campaign member via data loader.
It keeps throwing me this error **INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY: insufficient access rights on object id**
Like this I have 1 lakh records then 20000 will get insert and throw an error on 80k then again if I update the error records it will again insert 20000 and throw error on others.

I looked at some blogs they said set batch size 1 but I have a huge number of data.

Does anyone have any idea? Please let me know what's the issue here.

Comment: in dataloader,  All records processed in a particular batch  will fail  if error is encountered in any of the record.    as per the error you dont have sufficient  access on some records to perform update. either you can make sure that you have sufficuent access to update  or reduce batch size to some extent so that less records fail and fix them later

Comment: You don't have to go down to 1 record from the start. Maybe start at 500 then work your way down from the error files.